# hook_menu() (edit) not working

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I am doing something wrong and am not able to find what.

I have defined the hook_menu for my module, add and delete are working fine, but edit and view are not. Is like are never being called.

```
function nutrition_menu()
{
  $items['admin/structure/ingredients'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage Ingredients.',
    'description' => 'Manage Ingredients.',
    'access arguments' => array('administer ingredients'),
  );

  $items['ingredient/%ingredient'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'ingredient_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(1),
    'page callback' => 'ingredient_page_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('view ingredients'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

  );

  $items['ingredient/%ingredient/view'] = array(
    'title' => 'View',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10,

  ); 

  $items['ingredient/%ingredient/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callbacks' => 'ingredient_page_edit',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('update ingredients'),
    'weight' => 2,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,

  );

  $items['ingredient/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add new Ingredient:',
    'page callback' => 'ingredient_add',
    'access arguments' => array('create ingredients'),
    'weight' => 1,
    'menu_name' => 'management',
    'file' => 'ingredient.pages.inc',
  );  

  $items['ingredient/%ingredient/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('ingredient_delete_confirm',1),
    'access arguments' => array('delete ingredients'),
    'weight' => 1,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,

  );

  return $items;
}
```

load functions

```
function ingredient_load( $iid = NULL, $reset = NULL)
{
  $iids = (isset($iid) ? array($iid) : array() );
  $conditions = array();
  $ingredient = ingredient_load_multiple($iids, $conditions, $reset);
  return $ingredient ? reset($ingredient) : FALSE;
}


function ingredient_load_multiple($iids=array(),$conditions=array(),$reset=FALSE)
{
  return entity_load('ingredient', $iids, $conditions, $reset);
}
```

Callbacks

```
function ingredient_page_view($ingredient,$view_mode='full')
{
  $ingredient->content = array();

  field_attach_prepare_view('ingredient', array($ingredient->iid=>$ingredient),$view_mode);
  entity_prepare_view('ingredient',array($ingredient->iid=>$ingredient));
  $ingredient->content += field_attach_view('ingredient',$ingredient,$view_mode);

  return $ingredient->content;
}


function ingredient_page_edit($ingredient)
{
  var_dump($ingredient);

  drupal_set_title(t('Edit @name', array('@name' => $ingredient->name)), PASS_THROUGH);

  return drupal_get_form('ingredient_form',$ingredient);
}
```

Basically what I see is the two tabs ( View, Edit ) with no information bellow, the title isn't changing either.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? To me this looks like you're building an ingredient content type. If yes, almost all the code you show is not necessary. Have a look at the example module about how (http://drupal.org/project/examples) to build content types. There's even a good chance, that fields will do everything for you, which means you don't have to code anything.

Comment: I am creating a module ( entities included ) this is just a piece of code I copied and adapted from a book. Thanks for the advise though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'edit' page probably isn't working because you've mis-spelled `page callback` (it's currently spelt `page callbacks`).

Comment: Thank you @Clive. The Only thing missing is that view is not showing anything. Thanks!